# MATLAB: projective transformations

Tags: matlab, transformation, projective-geometry

I have a picture

[image]

and I want to get projective transformation by shifting it back like this:

[image]

but the only result I can see is this:

[image]

and I cannot find my mistake. My code (A - picture I want to transform):

```
p=0.25;
a=p*rows(A);

U = @(m, n) ([1 1; 1 m; n 1; n m]);
V = @(m, n) ([1+a 1+a; 1-a m-a; n-a 1+a; n+a m-a]);


D=transform(A, U(rows(A), cols(A)),...
               V(rows(A), cols(A)),...
               'projective');
imshow(D)

function B=transform(A,U,V,type)
[m n] = size(A)
tform = maketform(type,U,V);  
B = imtransform(A,tform,'size',[m n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the "directions" of your axes mixed up. Try this mapping:

```
V = @(m, n) ([1+a 1-a; 1+a m+a; n-a 1+a; n-a m-a]);
```

For the black background you can fix it by setting some parameter/value pair on `imtransform`

(Unfortunately I'm not at a computer with matlab, so I can't guarantee the correctness of the mapping. I'll check it tomorrow and update it if it is wrong)

Comment: Still not want I want. However, when I compile your code in my head, matlab gives me what I expect and with my code - not...

Comment: how can i do the inverted process?